# Sharing files between Android devices using Camera App

Tags: android, android-camera, file-sharing

My requirement is as follows.

I am developing an Android app in which one of the requirements is to share files saved in 1 device with another nearby device through Camera flash.

I have Googled a lot and am not able to come up with any known solutions for Android.

It will be of great help if someone can guide me about how to approach

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you want to get information like in morse alphabet using flash or what?

Comment: Dear Ferrux Nebiyev, not exactly, I want to know if there is any existing system with which I can transfer file saved in Android device 1 to nearby Android device 2 using Camera flash of the device